# How to Get the multiple radio buttons values in PHP which having names dynamically

Tags: php, forms

I am having following codings in my form..how do I get the value of all radio button values on submit which is inside looping? Or give me any other solution for this.

```
<form action="res.php" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
?>
        <div class="well well-sm well-primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="ques"/>Questions?
        </div>
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio<?php echo $i; ?>" value="a">Option 1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio<?php echo $i; ?>" value="b">Option 2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio<?php echo $i; ?>" value="c">Option 3
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Finish</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is always easier when doing the name as an array `name="optradio[$i]"` (ie. `name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]"`), then `name="optradio$i"` (ie. `name="optradio<?php echo $i; ?>"`)

Comment: Thank you so much.. Its working ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use array of radio button as follows

```
<form method="post">
    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="well well-sm well-primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="ques"/>Questions?
        </div>
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="a">Option 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="b">Option 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="c">Option 3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Finish</button>
</form>
```

To access the posted values, you can simply use `$_POST['optradio']`

Considering the selection for 5 questions to be **Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, Option 1, Option 2**
`POST['optradio']` will give array like

> Array ( [1] => a [2] => b [3] => c [4] => a [5] => b )

To access sigle values from this array, you can use `foreach` loop as,

```
<?php 
 foreach($_POST['optradio'] as $option_num => $option_val)
    echo $option_num." ".$option_val."<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

take a one hidden input for storing radio button name array in for loop
like

```
<input type="hidden" name="testradio[]" value="optradio<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

and then fetch radio button value using foreach

```
$rdobtn = $_POST['testradio'];
$idx = 0;

    foreach($rdobtn as $val){

      $rdovalue = $val[$idx];

      // perform opertation using above $rdovalue variable.

       $idx++;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Sean commented, try this:

```
<form action="res.php" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
?>
        <div class="well well-sm well-primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="ques"/>Questions?
        </div>
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="a">Option 1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="b">Option 2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="c">Option 3
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Finish</button>
</form>
```

and then use the below in PHP side to get radio button value as :

```
foreach ($_POST['optradio'] as $optNum => $option) {
    // do stuff with $optNum and $option
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`<input type="radio" name="optradio[]" value="a">`

And in PHP file,
`$_POST['optradio']` will result as an array.