# how to take mutiple values from radio button in php

Tags: php, html

i have form with 4 radio buttons like 
1) seth
2)roman
3)dean
4)others

if user clicks on others, a textbox will be open and user enters his own name

In php i want to take either form above 3 options whiich are selected by user or else from text box

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{

    $event =   trim($_POST['event']);
    $other_event = trim($_POST['other_event']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $info = trim($_POST['notes']);
    $upd_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//upl_date
    $ucode = md5(uniqid(rand()));

     if(empty($event) || ($other_event =='others' && empty($other_event)))
     {
         $errMSG = "Please enter camera name";
     }
     else
     {

        $event_name =  ($event =='others') ?  $other_event : $event;

        echo $event_name;

     }         
}
```

?>

my form :

```
     <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Meal Preference</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" id="calorieCheckbox" name="event" value="VIRINCHI" style="margin-right: 8px;">seth
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" id="saltCheckbox1" name="event" value="JOB_MELA " style="margin-right: 8px;">roman 
                        </label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" id="saltCheckbox2" name="event" value="MOCK_INTERVIEW" style="margin-right: 8px;"> dean
                        </label>
                    </div>
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label style="padding-bottom: 12px;">
                            <input type="radio" id="saltCheckbox3" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" value="others"  style="margin-right: 8px;">others
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9" style="display: none;" id="others">
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Event type" name="other_event" class="form-control">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get the multiple radio buttons values in PHP which having names dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013583/how-to-get-the-multiple-radio-buttons-values-in-php-which-having-names-dynamical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `name="event"` attr from the `value="others"` radio.
And

```
if(empty($event) || ($other_event =='others' && empty($other_event)))
```

should be

```
if(empty($event) || ($event =='others' && empty($other_event)))
```